# z-order (foreground/background) in pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, backgrounds, textpos

I am using the `wallpaper` package to put a pre-made PDF on the title page of my LaTeX document. On the same page, I use the `textpos` package to insert some text and an image (with `\includegraphics` inside the `textblock` environment provided by `textpos`).
This works beautifully, all is on the same page.

Compiled on OSX, the image is rendered **behind** the PDF.
Compiled on Windows, the image is **on top of** the PDF.

The problem is, the PDF contains a transparent window with rounded corners, so I need the image to go behind the PDF to be masked properly.

How can I determine the z-order in a LaTeX document?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. In particular, it would be useful to know exactly what binaries you are using here.

Comment: With no MWE, this is 'too localized'. Request reopening if more information is available.

Comment: For those stumbling on this, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23533/text-not-visible-if-positioned-over-included-colored-pdf: the solution is likely to use the `overlay` option to the `textpos` package.